# Stumped on wsgen + maven configuration

Tags: jax-ws, maven-plugin, wsgen

I've spent a whole day searching for a solution on how to get wsgen + maven to generate artifacts from my annotated class with no avail, always ending with the "Could not find class file" error.

My pom.xml looks like the following :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sei>fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.impl.ServiceWSConvergence</sei>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <sourceDestDir>target/generated-sources/artifacts</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.stub</packageName>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-MR1</version>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Besides, I tried generating the artifacts at command line with no better results :

```
wsgen -cp C:\workspace\ibabi\trunk\ibabi-ws\ibabi-ws-service\target\classes -keep -s C:/workspace/ibabi/trunk/ibabi-ws/ibabi-ws-service/target/generated-sources/artifacts fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.impl.ServiceWSConvergence
```

PS : I'm using the "classes" folder as the location of the endpoint class at command line. Using the src folder just returns an error with the command line input description.

Any help on this would really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Using command line wsgen

   ```
   wsgen -cp C:\workspace\ibabi\trunk\ibabi-ws\ibabi-ws-service\target\classes 
   -keep -s C:/workspace/ibabi/trunk/ibabi-ws/ibabi-ws-service/target/generated-       
   sources/artifacts 
   fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.impl.ServiceWSConvergence
   ```

   When running wsgen command, first confirm  source folder is *C:/workspace/ibabi/trunk/ibabi-ws/ibabi-ws-service/target/generated-sources/artifacts* and class files are generated inside 
   *C:\workspace\ibabi\trunk\ibabi-ws\ibabi-ws-service\target\classes*. 
   Before running wsgen,  *fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.impl.ServiceWSConvergence* bytecode file should be inside 
   *C:\workspace\ibabi\trunk\ibabi-ws\ibabi-ws-service\target\classes*.
2. Using Maven

   Use dependency from org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons instead of org.codehaus.mojo.  org.codehaus.mojo plugin has been migrated to  org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.
   Refer different valid options for maven wsgen from    http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html 
   If  project is based on default maven project structure, following sample snippet will work.

   ```
   <build>
     <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>              
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
               <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.1</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>wsgen</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>

               <configuration>
                   <sei>fr.extelia.ibabi.ws.convergence.impl.ServiceWSConvergence</sei>
                   <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
               </configuration>

               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                       <version>2.2.5</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```

If you still get problem, please post your project structure.

Comment: I can't seems to get it working. My code is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928429/wsgen-maven-configuration-didnt-generate-the-expected-file. Can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the target, but first to compile the service impl class.
mvn compile